# Android: Changing background color of a view dependent on input?

Tags: android, colors

I am currently attempting to change the background of a text view in my application dependent on data read on from a neurosky headset about a users mediation level.

Basically I want the textview to turn red if the mediation level dips below 30/100.

This functionality is working currently. However once the level dips below 30 and the textview  turns red, the red does not disapear even if the mediation level rises. (The level is measured once a second). How do I fix this?

Current code:

```
case TGDevice.MSG_MEDITATION:
                meditation.setText("Meditation: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");

                if(msg.arg1<=30){

                    //if mediation level is low it turns red
                    meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


                }
                break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why  not use an else part for the if clause like:

```
            if(msg.arg1<=30){

             //if mediation level is low it turns red
             meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            }else{
              meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.Your_color);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another If statement to check if the level has risen above 30 so that yo ucan change the color back?

```
case TGDevice.MSG_MEDITATION:
            meditation.setText("Meditation: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");

            if(msg.arg1<=30){

                //if mediation level is low it turns red
                meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


            }
            //new code is below
            else  if(msg.arg1>30){

                //if mediation level is high it turns to soem toher color
                meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.Blue);


            }
            break;
```